# Use also webpack in development environment

Tags: javascript, webpack

I followed the webpack official "get started" guide for a front end page and I'm wondering if it's intended to also be used in a development environment.

I managed to bundle all my foo.js dependencies but do I have to bundle everything together again each time I alter my foo.js or is there another way to be able to code and keep using the bundled dependencies?

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './foo.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'foo.bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
        }
    }
};
```

foo.js

```
require(['vue', 'jquery'], function(Vue, $){
    console.log(Vue);
    dynamo(Vue);
});
```

My planned workaround is to define a window.dynamo closure that is invoked in the afterwards loaded webpack bundle. The dynamo function would import the dev version foo.js (the one that is being developed on).

```html
    <script>
    window.dynamo = function(Vue){
        console.log(Vue);
    }
    </script>
    <script src="/js/foo.bundle.js"></script>
```

What are your thoughts on about webpack and dev environment?

Comment: Use webpack template. All has been done for you there. https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: My question doesn't specifically target a framework, but still thanks for pointing this out @connexo

Comment: All the modern frameworks have setups like that one. I really recommend using those, setting that up by yourself takes months.

Answer (score 0):

I found that passing the --watch parameter to webpack would make it watch all files and bundle them on the fly when one is modified:

```
webpack.js --watch
```

Also @connexo pointed on towards using https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack, which I didn't try yet because it implies knowledge about vue-cli. But it's definetly the next step.